# How to autoplay a Plotly chart in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have the following Shiny app with two animated barplots in plotly. I want them to play automatically upon loading (as in [here](https://pfdata.unocha.org/index.html), for instance). I need them to play only once (hopefully at the same time), just to give the impression that the bars "load", after that I don't need them to be animated anymore, so I'll have the buttons hidden.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56979808/12425067) shows a complicated (for me) way of doing so which I have not been able to adapt to my app. However, it mentions that *"animation might not actually be necessary for this example since the data points are not moving."*, which might work for me as the relevant value of `my_df` is only the first observation (which corresponds my last frame, as the other frames were only added to animate the bar).

I've also found [this plotly.github.io entry](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.io.write_html.html) where they mention a function with an `auto_play` argument which seems to do what I need, but I don't know where or how to use it.

In case it helps anyone come up with a solution I list here a couple posts with related questions ([this one is for dash-python](https://community.plotly.com/t/animated-chart-with-python-plotly-without-play-button/48311), and in [this one the OP asks for a way to press play using a shiny action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708762/how-do-i-link-a-shiny-action-button-to-a-plotly-animation-in-r) - which might help figure out a way of programmatically trigger the animation).

Any of the options (autoplaying, triggering the animation programmatically or a solution not involving plotly animation) works for me.

Here's my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)


my_df <- data.frame(
    vals = c(39, 0, 3.9, 7.8, 11.7, 15.6, 19.5, 23.4, 27.3, 31.2), 
    indic = rep("A", times = 10), 
    frame = c(10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))

ui <- fluidPage(plotlyOutput("first_plot", width = "50%"),
                plotlyOutput("second_plot", width = "50%"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$first_plot <- renderPlotly({
        plot_ly( data = my_df, y = ~indic, frame = ~frame, type = "bar", height = 200) %>% 
            add_trace(x = ~vals) %>% 
            layout(barmode = "stack") 
    }) 
    output$second_plot <- renderPlotly({
        plot_ly( data = my_df, y = ~indic, frame = ~frame, type = "bar", height = 200) %>% 
            add_trace(x = ~vals) %>% 
            layout(barmode = "stack") 
    }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Do you mean clicking the play buttons automatically whe the app starts?

Comment: Yes, I suppose one alternative is to "click" the play buttons automatically when the app starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the animation with JavaScript with the help of the `onRender` function. The animation will be played whenever the chart is rendered.

```r
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,1), 
  y = c(1,2,1), 
  f = c(1,2,3)
)
df %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~x,
    y = ~y,
    frame = ~f,
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'markers',
    marker = list(size = 20),
    showlegend = FALSE
  ) %>% 
  animation_button(visible = TRUE) %>%
  onRender("
        function(el,x) {
          Plotly.animate(el);
        }")
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But it stops `animation_opts(frame = 100)` from taking effect (whether I put it before or after `onRender()`) so must be overriding the output of this function.